# Using Linq in an Anon Type using one of the Anon Types Properties

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to see if I can combine 3 LINQ queries into one. The problem I am having is I need the value of one of the Anon properties in the where clause of one of the inner LINQ statements, which doesn't seem to work. I also tried to inline the LINQ statement but that didn't work either.

Has anyone done this before? The PlaceName is the one I am having trouble with as it uses the PlaceID.

```
        var Persons = from _person in people select new 
        { 
            ID = _person.Id,
            Name = _person.Name,
            Nationality = _person.Nationality,
            Age = _person.Age,
            PlaceID = (from _peopleplaces in peoplePlace where _person.Id ==_peopleplaces.PersonId select _peopleplaces.PlaceId).FirstOrDefault(),
            PlaceName = (from _places in places where _places.Id == PlaceID select _places.Name).FirstOrDefault()
        };
```

EDIT: The actual problem I am having is that PlaceID cannot be used in the PlaceName query, it has red squiggles under it. The reason for using 1 and not 3 statements is just for my own sake, I am learning LINQ and want to see what I can and can't do. I would have assumed it looks nicer to populate a Persons object using one set not 3 separate ones.

The actual error is PlaceID does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Why do not write distinct 3 queries? It's readable and easy and final result *most probably* will be the same, even in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you’re looking for the `let` keyword?

```
var Persons = 
    from _person in people
    let placeID = 
    (
        from _peopleplaces in peoplePlace
        where _person.Id == _peopleplaces.PersonId 
        select _peopleplaces.PlaceId
    ).FirstOrDefault()
    let placeName =
    (
        from _places in places
        where _places.Id == placeID 
        select _places.Name
    ).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        ID = _person.Id,
        Name = _person.Name,
        Nationality = _person.Nationality,
        Age = _person.Age,
        PlaceID = placeID,
        PlaceName = placeName,
    };
```

**Edit**: As @sambomartin correctly mentioned below, you need to consider what would happen if there is no entry in `peoplePlace` for a specific person. Under the above query, such persons are still returned in the final result, with a `PlaceID` and `PlaceName` of `null`.

C# allows equality comparison between an `int` and a `int?`; if the latter is `null`, the comparison would always evaluate to `false`. Thus, when `placeID` is `null`, no entry from `places` would satisfy the `_places.Id == placeID` condition (assuming the `Id` field is not nullable), and `placeName` would evaluate to `null` as well.

If you do not want such persons in your final result, you could amend your query by adding `where` clauses:

```
var Persons = 
    from _person in people
    let placeID = 
    (
        from _peopleplaces in peoplePlace
        where _person.Id == _peopleplaces.PersonId 
        select _peopleplaces.PlaceId
    ).FirstOrDefault()
    where placeID != null   // ensure that the person has an associated place
    let placeName =
    (
        from _places in places
        where _places.Id == placeID 
        select _places.Name
    ).FirstOrDefault()
    where placeName != null   // ensure that the place appears in the primary table
    select new
    {
        ID = _person.Id,
        Name = _person.Name,
        Nationality = _person.Nationality,
        Age = _person.Age,
        PlaceID = placeID,
        PlaceName = placeName,
    };
```

Comment: I had to give it to you as this this allows much more control.

Comment: I'm glad we helped you. Just one thing to consider is that I'm not sure without checking, but FirstOrDefault will return a null if no record is found. You might get exception if placeId is null in the second 'let' is places.Id is not nullable.

Comment: @Douglas thanks for edit, but it seems a long winded solution to joining a few objects together into a collection. I would typically use 'let' to prevent unnecessarily evaluating the same value multiple times in a query.  I'm not sure I'd use it how you have? Is there any benefit in doing so?

Comment: `let` is typically used for constructing what would be translated into a nested subquery in SQL. In this case, the question implied that only the _first_ place for each person should be projected. Your answer projects _all_ places for a given person. To adapt it to achieve the desired result using a join, you would probably need to project row indexes as well, which might not get translated into efficient SQL. (I believe that projection of row indexes is DBMS-specific.)

Comment: @Douglas thanks for the edit, your first sample was fine though, I was looking for all people. Then from there I wanted to assign a place (id and place) if there is one or null otherwise. Granted my request is convoluted but I was just trying to see if I could use LINQ over akward data, so far, its preforming like a champ :)

Comment: Your request is not that convoluted; there are several scenarios where one would need to group data by a given field, and then retrieve the first element for each group. In Transact-SQL, you could achieve this using a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY` query.

Answer (score 3):

You cant use the PlaceId until it's been calculated, I.e. when its enumerated.

There's nothing to stop you querying the three objects in a single expression, e.g.

```
var people = from p in Persons
             from ppl in PersonPlaces
             From pl in Places
             where p.Id == ppl.PersonId
             && ppl.PlaceId == pl.Id
             select new { Name=p.Name, PlaceName=pl.Name}
```

Sorry for formatting, it's difficult on iPad.

Hth

Sam

Comment: DOH! That's pretty much what I wanted to do but didn't think you could.. pragmatism eh :)

Comment: Yeah, or you could use let ... of course as per Douglas answer. Depends what you need to return in top query.